# Javascript hiding objects in loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Please help me. I want to hide ext by clicking on link, but something is wrong

But I could write only this, and don't undertand why it's not working! Maybe there is another way to do it? It's every time fills the same function. to li1 li2func, therefore thereis li1
 [Link to jsfiddler](https://jsfiddle.net/3rhzxsbg/)

html:`

```
<div>

<div class="left">
<ul>
        <li><a id="11" href="#">one</a></li>
        <li><a  id="12" href="#">two</a></li>
        <li><a id="13" href="#">three</a></li>
    </ul>

  </div>
  <div class="right">
  <p id="1">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Doloremque, qui.
  </p>
  <p id="2">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Repellendus reiciendis veritatis voluptatibus optio explicabo? Dignissimos ex amet mollitia doloribus a.
  </p>
  <p id="3">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Impedit porro quisquam harum nemo, vitae itaque.</p>
  </div>

</div>`
```

JS code:

```
var el = document.getElementsByTagName("p");
var cs = document.getElementsByTagName("a");
if(el) {
    for (i = 0; i < el.length; i++) {
        td = cs[i];
        (function (_td) {
            td.addEventListener('click', function(){
                console.log(_td);
                console.log(i);
                document.getElementsByTagName("div")[i].className +=  document.getElementsByTagName("div")[i].className ? ' invis' : 'invis';
            });
        })(td);
```

Comment: what does the title says? is it a question or a statement, I don't get it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a few problems with your javascript. You should have noticed this error in your javascript console: "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'className' of undefined", which might have led you to discover that `document.getElementsByTagName("div")` is not the selector you should be using. You did the work to produce an array of `p` tags (inexplicably named `el`), but then didn't make any reference to that within the closure you built.

Here's one way to fix that problem: give your closure a second argument, and pass the `p` tag of the corresponding number (`i`) to the `a` tag to which you're binding the click handler. Then modify the `className` string of *that* element.

```
var el = document.getElementsByTagName("p");
var cs = document.getElementsByTagName("a");

if(el) {
    for (i = 0; i < el.length; i++) {
         td = cs[i];
         ptag = el[i];
          (function (_td,_el) {
        td.addEventListener('click', function(){
            console.log(_td);
             console.log(i);
             _el.className += _el.className ? ' invis' : 'invis';
        });
    })(td,ptag);
    }
}
```

One other thing: you'll notice that `console.log(i)` always produces 3 because that `i` is not bound to the scope of the click handler, but rather the outer scope of the `for` loop, so when the user clicks on one of the `a` tags, the loop has already completed and `i` will always equal 3.

Comment: yes, there were a few mistakes, but i will always equal 3 - that was s real problem, I can't solve to. Thanks a lot, its really what I want to do.

Answer (score 1):

While you tagged `jquery` this is how can you do with jquery *by using the `index()` of href's closest li*

```js
$('ul > li > a').on('click' , function(){
    var ThisId = $(this).closest('li').index();
    $('div.right > p:eq('+ThisId+')').slideToggle(100);
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>

  <div class="left">
    <ul>
      <li><a id="11" href="#">one</a></li>
      <li><a id="12" href="#">two</a></li>
      <li><a id="13" href="#">three</a></li>
    </ul>

  </div>
  <div class="right">
    <p id="1">
      1 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Doloremque, qui.
    </p>
    <p id="2">
      2 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Repellendus reiciendis veritatis voluptatibus optio explicabo? Dignissimos ex amet mollitia doloribus a.
    </p>
    <p id="3">3 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Impedit porro quisquam harum nemo, vitae itaque.</p>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: that's greate! Thanks a lot! I hadn't ever mind this way to do!

Comment: @user2986966 You're welcome .. *jquery is much easier than pure js* Have a great day :-)

Answer (score 1):

document.getElementsByTagName will never return null, so if(el) in your code is unnecessary. An empty array will always evaluate to true. If you want i to not equal 3, then you have to add it to the closure at the moment it is 0, 1, and 2. I called it _index here:

```
var paragraphs = document.getElementsByTagName("p");
var links = document.getElementsByTagName("a");

for (i = 0; i < paragraphs.length; i++) {
     link = links[i];
     paragraph = paragraphs[i];
     (function (_link,_paragraph, _index) {
         _link.addEventListener('click', function(){
             console.log(_link);
             console.log(_index);
             _paragraph.classList.toggle('invis');
        });
    })(link,paragraph, i);
}
```

Here is a cleaner version

```
function init(link, paragraph, index) {
    link.addEventListener('click', function(){
         paragraph.classList.toggle('invis');
    });
}

var paragraphs = document.getElementsByTagName("p");
var links = document.getElementsByTagName("a");

for (i = 0; i < paragraphs.length; i++) {
    init(links[i], paragraphs[i], i);
}
```